# How to make vuetify auto-complete components independent from each other

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i am developing an invoice app in with vuetify. i have encounter a problem, when i select a product for one row. it populates other rows.**How do i make each autocomplete component independent from each other
** [image]

**This is the auto-complete component**

```
 <tr v-for="(stock_item, index) in form.stock_items" :key="stock_item.data">
                        <td class="pb-n12">{{index+1}}</td>
                        <td class="pt-4" @click="getIndex(index)">
                            <v-autocomplete
                                v-model="product"
                                :items="GET_PRODUCTS"
                                item-text="description"
                                item-value="id"
                                :return-object="true"
                                background-color="#fefeff"
                                label="Select Product"
                                full-width
                                dense
                                solo

                                hint="list of all products"
                            >
                            </v-autocomplete>
                        </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because each `<v-autocomplete/>` item shares the same `<v-model>`. Here you're iterating the list of fields and each field gets `v-model="product"` and this `product` data variable applies to all of them. The solution is to create a store for each field, where the model will be kept and updated only for that particular field. This can be done in this way:

Create an array of objects for each field and one property which (`dataModel`) holds the its model:

```
  data: () => ({
    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    fields: [{
      dataModel: ['foo', 'bar']
    }, {
      dataModel: ['foo', 'bar']
    }],
  }),
```

Then in the template use `item.dataModel` for each `v-autocomplete`:

```
<v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row
          align="center"
        >
          <v-col cols="12" v-for="item in fields">
            <v-autocomplete
              v-model="item.dataModel"
              :items="items"
              outlined
              dense
              chips
              small-chips
              label="Outlined"
              multiple
            ></v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
```

Live Example:
https://codepen.io/nyankov/pen/PoZzegV?editors=1010